# How to find out resolution and count of frames in YUV 4:2:0 file?

Tags: yuv

How to find out resolution and count of frames in YUV 4:2:0 file if i know how many pixel(luma samples) in the image?

Answer (score 30):

YUV 4:2:0 planar looks like this:

```
----------------------
|     Y      | Cb|Cr |
----------------------
```

where:

```
Y = width x height pixels (bytes)
Cb = Y / 4 pixels (bytes)
Cr = Y / 4 pixels (bytes)

Total num pixels (bytes) = width * height * 3 / 2
```

This is how pixels are placed in 4:2:0 sub-sampling:

[image: 420]

As you can see, each chroma value is shared between 4 luma-pixels.

Basically, the only thing you can do is to see which frame-sizes divides the
total file-size evenly.

As an example, consider the classic forman-clip, which you can download from http://trace.eas.asu.edu/yuv/foreman/foreman_cif.7z

The size of that clip is `45619200` bytes. How do one get the dimensions and number of frames from that? Try different resolutions!

is it [SDTV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SDTV)?

```
In [7]: 45619200 / float(720*576*3/2)
Out[7]: 73.33333333333333
```

nope!

is it [QCIF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QCIF)?

```
In [8]: 45619200 / float(176*144*3/2)
Out[8]: 1200.0
```

might be...

is it CIF?

```
In [9]: 45619200 / float(352*288*3/2)
Out[9]: 300.0
```

might be...

Only way to find out is trying to display it.

Let's try QCIF

[image: wring]

that doesn't look right. Lets try CIF

[image: right]

[Bingo!](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bingo)

Comment: Based on your note: **Total num pixels (bytes) = width * height * 3 / 2** you can calculate **widthHeight = frameSize * 2 / 3;**  Then you could check the common sizes for a match.  Or go for the common aspect ratio of 4:3. **width = widthHeight / 3; height = widthHeight / 4; check = width * height; ASSERT(check == widthHeight);**  There are, of course, other aspect ratios to check.  16:9 for high def for example.

Comment: You are absolutely right. My idea with this answer was just to provide some basic insight to get the OP started. You can spend a lifetime investigating all aspects of YCbCr-data :-)

Comment: re: lifetime - Yep. This OP is just about 4:2:0, it all changes if you're talking 4:2:2 or any of the other variations of YCbCr.  And converting to other color formats (RGB) even changes  if you are talking co-sited.  Your answer is an excellent primer for YCbCr 4:2:0. Those who have need for the gory details of the rest are reading thick tomes. ;-D