# How to get Bitmap from session.update() in ARCore [Android Studio]

Tags: java, android, bitmap, bitmapfactory, arcore

I am trying to get a Bitmap from the current frame of my ARSession with ARCore. But it always equals null. I've already been searching the web for quite a while but cannot figure out what I am doing wrong.

```
try {
    capturedImage = mFrame.acquireCameraImage();

    ByteBuffer buffer = capturedImage.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();

    byte[] bytes = new byte[buffer.capacity()];

    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length,null);

    if (bitmap == null) 
        Log.e(TAG,"Bitmap was NOT initialized!");

} catch(Exception e){

}
```

I am getting `mFrame` from `onDrawFrame` of my `GLSurfaceView` which I use to display the camera image. Everything works just fine except that my Bitmap equals null.

I am using a Button, so that only a single Frame is being used, as follows:

```
scanButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.scanButton);
scanButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        checkbox = false;
        if (capturedImage!=null) capturedImage.close();
            BitmapMethod();
    }
});
```

`capturedImage`, `buffer` and `bytes` all do not equal null.

Is there probably something wrong with `mFrame.acquireCameraImage()`?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is there probably something wrong with mFrame.acquireCameraImage()?

No, `mFrame.acquireCameraImage()` works as intended.

> But it always equals null

The Bitmap will always equal null since bitmap factory does not understand the image data that is passed to it.

The method `mFrame.acquireCameraImage()` responds with an object of type `Image` that is in the YUV format or YCbCr. These types of images have 3 planes which is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19677747/how-to-find-out-resolution-and-count-of-frames-in-yuv-420-file) very nicely. The `ByteArray` contained in these planes may be read directly by a CPU/GPU in `native` code. `BitmapFactory` cannot read this type of data. Hence, you need to convert this YUV image into something else.

For that, you need to use [`YuvImage`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/YuvImage.html#compressToJpeg(android.graphics.Rect,%20int,%20java.io.OutputStream)) class to create an instance of YUV & then convert it into JPEG using the `compressToJpeg` method. Once you have the byteArray from this, you can simply do what you're doing above. Use `BitmapFactory` to convert it into Bitmap and add it to your `ImageView`.

Note : YUV has 3 planes. Create a single bytearray from all planes & then pass it to YUV constructor. Though not elaborate, it should look something similar to this :

```
//The camera image received is in YUV YCbCr Format. Get buffers for each of the planes and use them to create a new bytearray defined by the size of all three buffers combined
val cameraPlaneY = cameraImage.planes[0].buffer
val cameraPlaneU = cameraImage.planes[1].buffer
val cameraPlaneV = cameraImage.planes[2].buffer

//Use the buffers to create a new byteArray that 
val compositeByteArray = ByteArray(cameraPlaneY.capacity() + cameraPlaneU.capacity() + cameraPlaneV.capacity())

cameraPlaneY.get(compositeByteArray, 0, cameraPlaneY.capacity())
cameraPlaneU.get(compositeByteArray, cameraPlaneY.capacity(), cameraPlaneU.capacity())
cameraPlaneV.get(compositeByteArray, cameraPlaneY.capacity() + cameraPlaneU.capacity(), cameraPlaneV.capacity())

val baOutputStream = ByteArrayOutputStream()
val yuvImage: YuvImage = YuvImage(compositeByteArray, ImageFormat.NV21, cameraImage.width, cameraImage.height, null)
yuvImage.compressToJpeg(Rect(0, 0, cameraImage.width, cameraImage.height), 75, baOutputStream)
val byteForBitmap = baOutputStream.toByteArray()
val bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteForBitmap, 0, byteForBitmap.size)
imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap)
```

That's just a rough code. It has scope for improvement perhaps. Also refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9192982/displaying-yuv-image-in-android).

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanation! It works perfectly. (Though I first had to find my way through your Kotlin code haha).

Comment: Very good explanation. Worked like charm.

Comment: I'm glad people still find this useful. I've been so out of touch, my own response looks surreal to me. :D

Comment: For the NV21 conversion from YUV_420_888 I need this more robust conversion since my input a little differnt:   https://stackoverflow.com/a/52740776/83370  , but your solution got me on the right track!  Thanks!

Comment: Blueish colour is more

Answer (score 0):

I also winded up recreating the same situation as you were facing. I was getting the Image object as Null.

After some research, I found the problem was in the flow of the logic.

I then wrote the following code and it solved my issue:

**I defined the following boolean to be set to capture the current frame on the button click:**

```
private static boolean captureCurrentFrame = false;
```

**This code I wrote in the onClick() function to get the current frame's RGB and Depth Image:**

```
public void captureFrame(View view){
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Capturing depth and rgb photo",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    captureCurrentFrame = true;
  }
```

**This section I wrote in onDrawFrame() method just after getting the frame from session.update():**

```
if(captureCurrentFrame) {
        RGBImage = frame.acquireCameraImage();
        DepthImage = frame.acquireDepthImage();

        Log.d("Image","Format of the RGB Image: " + RGBImage.getFormat());
        Log.d("Image","Format of the Depth Image: " + DepthImage.getFormat());

        RGBImage.close();
        DepthImage.close();

        captureCurrentFrame = false;
      }
```

Reason for getting Null in my case was the code in the onClick listener was getting triggered before going through the onDraw() method, as a result of which the Images were not stored in the variables.

Therefore, I shifted the logic to onDraw() and triggered that flow through the boolean variable that is set by the listener.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if there is anybody still looking for the answer, but this is my code.

```
        Image image = mFrame.acquireCameraImage();
        byte[] nv21;
        // Get the three planes.
        ByteBuffer yBuffer = image.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();
        ByteBuffer uBuffer = image.getPlanes()[1].getBuffer();
        ByteBuffer vBuffer = image.getPlanes()[2].getBuffer();

        int ySize = yBuffer.remaining();
        int uSize = uBuffer.remaining();
        int vSize = vBuffer.remaining();


        nv21 = new byte[ySize + uSize + vSize];

        //U and V are swapped
        yBuffer.get(nv21, 0, ySize);
        vBuffer.get(nv21, ySize, vSize);
        uBuffer.get(nv21, ySize + vSize, uSize);

        int width = image.getWidth();
        int height = image.getHeight();

        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        YuvImage yuv = new YuvImage(nv21, ImageFormat.NV21, width, height, null);
        yuv.compressToJpeg(new Rect(0, 0, width, height), 100, out);
        byte[] byteArray = out.toByteArray();
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);
```

Comment: Can you explain why this is the answer and how you changed the OP code to acheive it?